# Can super() only be called from within the child class constructor? | Java

Tags: java, inheritance, super

So I understand that `super()` calls the constructor of the parent class and I have used it on multiple occasions. However, I have never used it outside of the constructor of the child class. Is it possible to call `super()` from outside the child class constructor? Since `super` only makes sense when it is attached to a derived class, can it be treated like a member function of the derived class? I initially had this problem while trying to call super using an object (Just experimenting).

Is it possible to do something like this?

```java
class Animal {
    Animal() {
        System.out.println("Animal's constructor was called.");
    }
}

class Puppy extends Animal {
    Puppy() {
        System.out.println("Puppy's constructor was called.");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Puppy pupper = new Puppy();
        pupper.super();
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Why would you want to do this? This does not make much sense.

Comment: For this example, true, but how should I approach initializing the values of just the parent class data members.

Comment: So you want an instance of the child class, but with only its inherited members initialised? Why would you _ever_ want a half-initialised object? This looks like a very big [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, my bad. I've deviated from what I really wanted to ask. My main concern is whether super() can be called from anywhere apart from the child class constructor. (Just to understand what is and what isn't possible with super())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible, not outside of a constructor body.

The [Java Language Specification § 8.8.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1) says the following:

> ```
> ExplicitConstructorInvocation:
>   [TypeArguments] this ( [ArgumentList] ) ;
>   [TypeArguments] super ( [ArgumentList] ) ;
>   ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] super ( [ArgumentList] ) ;
>   Primary . [TypeArguments] super ( [ArgumentList] ) ;
> ```

Here, within the constructor body ([§ 8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)), `super()` is allowed, but nowhere else.